# How to see the query being executed when the SQL thread is in "Reading event from the realy log" state for a long time

Tags: mysql, replication

On one of my production servers, I have seen the SLQ thread in the below mentioned state for about 10 hours(35000 seconds).

```
Reading events from the relay log
(means that SQL thread has read and event from the relay log)
```

Then what is the thread doing since that long even after reading an event??

I believe that is running some query. But I could only see "NULL" under the "Info" filed where i am expecting the query.

If it is running a query which is not visible under the info filed, how to see that query or what does this situation mean...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Slave lag is around 2 and half hours and is increasing gradually during this time. I tried to see what is causing the issue but unable to see any query running from the slave SQL thread.

Comment: BY the way, replication mode is MIXED mode. I think this is the reason behind that I could nt see what is tha actual query being executed... Is it...???